# C# Out of context method

Tags: c#, asp.net

first time poster long term user. I am working on an ASP assignment for school and am stuck! I've spent 10 hours trying to solve it on my own.

The assignment is to build a student registration system. The user enters their name, selects their student type (part-time, full-time or co-op) and chooses their courses (checkboxes). The user then clicks submit. The application then displays an ASP table which contains the chosen courses.

Part-time, full-time and co-op are all classes which have the base class of Student. The courses that were selected are stored in an ArrayList called enrolledCourses in the Student class. The ArrayList is protected. I have a public ArrayList method called getEnrolledCourses which returns enrolledCourses. The method is inside the Student class as well.

When the user clicks submit, the event executes a method called buildTable(student).

Inside the buildTable method, I create an ASP table and hard-coded the first row of the table which are the column names. Then I have a foreach loop which is suppose to output each course. The column names output fine but none of the courses do.

My foreach statement is

```
foreach (Course course in student.getEnrolledCourses())
```

When I debug, I get the error:

> getEnrolledCourses    The name 'getEnrolledCourses' does not exist in the
>   current context    getEnrolledCourses The name 'getEnrolledCourses' does
>   not exist in the current context

(Yes, twice)

Here is my webpage's code behind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class CourseRegistration : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)  {
            Header.Title = "Course Registration";
        }

        foreach (Course c in Helper.GetCourses())
        {
            CheckBox cb = new CheckBox();
            cb.ID = "cb" + c.Code;
            cb.Text = c.ToString();

            Literal br = new Literal();
            br.Text = "<br/>";

            pnlCourses.Controls.Add(cb);
            pnlCourses.Controls.Add(br);
        }
    }
    protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (txtName.Text != "" && (rdbtnCoop.Checked || rdbtnFull.Checked || rdbtnPart.Checked))
        {
            pnlFirst.Visible = false;
            pnlSecond.Visible = true;
            Student student = new FullTimeStudent(txtName.Text);

            if (rdbtnFull.Checked)
                student = new FullTimeStudent(txtName.Text);
            else if (rdbtnPart.Checked)
                student = new PartTimeStudent(txtName.Text);
            else if (rdbtnCoop.Checked)
                student = new CoopStudent(txtName.Text);

            lblThanks.Text = "Thanks, <span class='error'>" + student.Name + "</span>, ";
            lblInfo.Text = "Fill in";
            buildTable(student);
        }
    }

    protected void buildTable(Student student)
    {
        TableHeaderRow thr = new TableHeaderRow();
        TableHeaderCell thdCode = new TableHeaderCell();
        TableHeaderCell thdTitle = new TableHeaderCell();
        TableHeaderCell thdHours = new TableHeaderCell();
        TableHeaderCell thdFee = new TableHeaderCell();

        thdCode.Text = "Course Code";
        thdTitle.Text = "Course Title";
        thdHours.Text = "Weekly Hours";
        thdFee.Text = "Fee Payable";

        thr.Controls.Add(thdCode);
        thr.Controls.Add(thdTitle);
        thr.Controls.Add(thdHours);
        thr.Controls.Add(thdFee);

        tblCourses.Controls.Add(thr);


        TableRow tr = new TableRow();
        TableCell tdCode = new TableCell();
        TableCell tdTitle = new TableCell();
        TableCell tdHours = new TableCell();
        TableCell tdFee = new TableCell();

        int totalHours = 0;
        double totalFee = 0.0;

        foreach (Course course in student.getEnrolledCourses())
        {
            tdCode.Text = course.Code;
            tdTitle.Text = course.Title;
            totalHours += course.WeeklyHours;
            tdHours.Text = course.WeeklyHours.ToString();
            totalFee += course.Fee;
            tdFee.Text = course.Fee.ToString();

            tr.Controls.Add(tdCode);
            tr.Controls.Add(tdTitle);
            tr.Controls.Add(tdHours);
            tr.Controls.Add(tdFee);

            tblCourses.Controls.Add(tr);
        }
        //TableFooterRow tfr = new TableFooterRow();       
    }
}
```

Here is the Student class

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

/// <summary>
/// Summary description for Student
/// </summary>
public abstract class Student
{
    private string name;

    protected ArrayList enrolledCourses;

    protected Student(string name)
    {
        this.name = name;
        enrolledCourses = new ArrayList();
    }

    public string Name {
        get { return name; }
    }

    public ArrayList getEnrolledCourses() {
        return enrolledCourses;
    }

    public int totalWeeklyHours()
    {
        int totalHours = 0;
        foreach (Course course in enrolledCourses) {
            totalHours += course.WeeklyHours;
        }
        return totalHours;
    }

    public virtual double feePayable()
    {
        double totalFee = 0.0;
        foreach (Course course in enrolledCourses) {
            totalFee += course.Fee;
        }
        return totalFee;
    }

    public abstract void addCourse(Course course);
}
```

I would greatly appreciate any help you can provide. Thanks.

Comment: Try changing your usages of ArrayList to List<Course>

Comment: Clearly the Student class has a public method of that name. So I don't think the problem is in the code you've posted.  Some questions: (1) Are you saying this is a runtime error? Or does it not even compile. (2) What version of Visual Studio is this, because I'm puzzled there are no automatically generated namespace declarations surrounding your classes? (3) Have you made sure your solution and project configurations are set to build everything? (In Solution Explorer, right-click the solution, choose Configuration Manager, and make sure everything is selected to build.)

Comment: To get any further, you're going to need to [provide a minimal example of complete code that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). As it's already quite a lot of code, I suggest you make a copy of the whole project and chop out everything that you find is not necessary to reproduce the issue, and post the minimum code that does reproduce it.

Answer (score -1):

You are trying to enumerate the the return value of `student.getEnrolledCourses()` to a `Course` object, however, the abstract class returns a value of `ArrayList`.

As we don't see the concrete implementation of your `Student` class, we can't see what the items are in your `ArrayList` object.

Please check that `ArrayList` does include `Course` items by changing:

```
foreach (Course course in student.getEnrolledCourses())
{
```

to

```
ArrayList list = student.getEnrolledCourses();
foreach (Course course in list)
{
```

I would then set a breakpoint on the `foreach` keyword and check the contents of `list` using a Watch Window.

You may also want to check that your incoming `Student` object is not null at the top of the `buildTable` method:

```
if(student == null)
    throw new ArgumentNullException("student");
```